# Centering custom control horizontally in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, css, position

This is more like a CSS question than a GIS one. But I don't have any clue how to center an element that has an absolute position.

---

Here's some relevant markup for my icon category selector that I create using `ol.control.defaults().extend( new myCustomControlFunction() );` (it's used within a Wordpress plugin that I'm writing and the category buttons are created dynamically based upon the Wordpress categories):

```
`<div class="ol-taxonomy-selector ol-unselectable ol-control">
    <span class="selectbuttons">
        <button class="category-name" name="catid" onclick="iconSelectCat(this)">Category Name</button>
        <!-- one button for each category here -->
    </span>
    <button class="mobiletoggle"></button>
</div>`
```

I want to center the horizontal category select bar at the bottom of the map. In ol.css, ".ol-button" is set to position:absolute so that I can position it left, right, top, bottom. But how do I center an element that has position:absolute and a variable width?

It's more a general CSS question but with the code you can see where I want to apply it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Perhaps you could show some relevant code/CSS markup?

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! I added the HTML markup above and explained the CSS a bit. I think it's a clear CSS question, but as other Openlayers 3 users might wish to center control buttons, I thought it might be useful to discuss it here.

Comment: How about a feedback?

Answer (score 1):

To give you some inspiration, for instance, if you want the zoom control positioned at the center bottom of the map you can use:

```
.ol-control.ol-zoom{

    top: -moz-calc(100% - 65px);
    top: -webkit-calc(100% - 65px);
    top: calc(100% - 65px);
    left: -moz-calc(50% - 33px);
    left: -webkit-calc(50% - 33px);
    left: calc(50% - 33px);

}
```

where `65px` is the computed height of the control and `33px` the width. The vendor prefix (`-moz-calc, -webkit-calc`) is to give more browser compatibility.

And this CSS declaration `.ol-control.ol-zoom` means:

apply only when these two are in the same HTML element, e.g.:

`<div class="ol-zoom ol-control">`

**UPDATE**

You can also appeal to another CSS resource:

```
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

[Here's a demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhuCEN?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea. I never used CSS3 calc for positioning and I will give it at try. However, this does not work for element that have a variable width, right? I have horizontal category select buttons for my icons at the bottom of my map and they include the category name which has a variable length.

Comment: I've updated my answer.